# ZF file element is not printing any error message

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I created a stand alone zend form for uploading files and I set the file element as a required field.  But the file element is not printing out any error message.

I set the decorators for the file element like so:

```
// The file element requires the File decorator instead of the 
// ViewHelper decorator
$file->setDecorators(array(
    'File',
    'Errors',
));
```

I pasted the code here: http://pastebin.com/0D59pxiR

I pasted the template here: http://pastebin.com/SRYh71JN

What am I doing wrong?  I thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to print out enctype="element->getEnctype();?> and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to split the ispost and the isvalid:

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] )) {
    if ($form->isValid( $_POST )){
    echo 'Thank you';
    }
    //if is post but not valid reload page and render the errors
    echo $form->render( $view );//render form with errors
    echo $form->getMessages($view);//or just render the messages back to the view
} else {
    echo $form->render( $view );//if not post render form
}
```

This is my best guess.

**[Edit]**

have you tried

```
$file->addDecorator('File');
```

instead of

```
$file->setDecorators(array(
    'File',
    'Errors',
));
```

The form level setElementDecorators maybe somehow interferring with setting the file element decorators. addDecorator() or addDecorators() should prevent that.

I would also suggest you try using the default decorators for test to rule out any other potential issues.

I don't see anything obvious. The only thing that's really different is that the File element proxies isValid() to Zend_File_Transfer. I suppose there could be an issue there, but if there were I would expect a significant error message.

Comment: It did not work.  Plus, the form already printed out all errors except for file element errors.